# How do I create custom axes in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts, axis

I'm creating a "histogram" and need the values of "frequency" to be displayed in ascending or descending order, which means that I need custom values for the x-axis.  Instead of having:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

I need to have this be values of cells:

> 85 93 45 43 67 89 43

Is there anyway of doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lay out your data in the following format:

```
Category        Frequency
 85           3
 93           6 
 45           12
 43           20
 67           13
 89           5
 43           2
```

Start by inserting a new *blank* chat. Do not select any data. I would suggest using a column chart for this. Just go to `Insert` -> `Chart` -> `Column` -> `2D Column`. It should be blank:

[image: excel image]

On the `Design` tab of the `Chat Tools` section of the Ribbon, click on `Select Data`. Under legend entries, click `Add`.

[image: excel image]

Select the *Series Values* box (*not* the "Series Name" box), and click+drag to select all of the data in the *frequency* column.

[image: excel image]

Click OK. Now, back in the Select Data dialog, click `Edit` on the "Horizontal Axis Labels".

[image: edit axis labels]

Click+drag to select the *Category* column:

[image: edit titles]

Now click OK on everything and set whatever other legend, title, and other settings you wish!

Comment: I feel like an idiot for not spotting that.  Good post.

Comment: nhinkle: what are you using for those screenshots? I usually use the Windows 7 Snipping Tool, but the results aren't usually that clean.

Comment: @TuxRug, I use [Shotty](http://shotty.devs-on.net/en/Overview.aspx), as suggested in "[Free screenshot program that respects Aero's transparency layer](http://superuser.com/q/148738/20088)". It doesn't always work perfectly, but most of the time, it does a great job of capturing nice clean screenshots with transparent windows and window shadows.

Comment: In Windows, you can also use the shortcut ctrl+shift+printscreen @TuxRug which will take a screen shot of the currently active window.

Comment: @KronoS: yes, but not as nice-looking.

Answer (score 1):

Next time you make this kind of chart, clear the label above the column of X values (A1 here, "Category"). The blank cell indicates to Excel that the first column and top row are different, so Excel will use the first column for axis labels and the first row for series names.